Can I burn a Mac file on DVD in Windows then install on a Mac?
I want to buy Mac software as a gift but I have a Windows machine. Could I purchase the software and download it on my Windows machine then burn it to DVD for someone to install on a Mac?

Yes, but who uses DVDs in 2024? You can use any mass storage device or just send the link to the person...

Do you have a reason to believe you would not be able to do this?

@ChanganAuto I still use an 8 track player. j/k. :)

Just to be clear if the recipient has a Mac laptop its very likely that they won't have any way to play the DVD - its been a very long time since Mac laptops had internal DVD players and most Mac users don't have/need an external DVD reader.

Thanks for the help. I should be good.

Yes, you can do this.
Keep in mind that software for mac is not the same as software for windows. You can't just put .exe files on there and expect them to work on a mac. But if the software is for a mac, you can just burn that to DVD. Note that most macs don't have an optical drive anymore, but you can use an external DVD player with USB interface.
Of course, you can do the same with a USB stick or other portable media. Keep in mind that if you go this route, that you must ensure that the filesystem on that USB stick is supported by MAC. FAT32 is, NTFS only after you install software. If your drive is larger than 32 GB, then you can use ExFAT, which is also fully supported on a mac.


“Could I purchase the software and download it on my Windows machine then burn it to DVD for someone to install on a Mac?”

Why? Most all Macs nowadays don’t come with CD/DVD optical drives to begin with. The last Mac that had an optical drive is the mid-2012 MacBook Pro (13-inch).
Unless you plan on giving them a CD/DVD optical drive as well, you are better off putting the software on a USB flash drive instead. Every Mac out there has at least one USB port.
As an added convenience, you might want to find out if the recipient's Mac has USB-A or USB-C ports. USB-A to USB-C adapters are fairly commonplace and very affordable. Or you can explicitly get USB flash drive that best fits their needs: A USB-A flash drive or a USB-C flash drive.
